# How to set php variable as value of input in html form for those input with type "file"

Tags: php, html

we can set PHP variable as the value of input in HTML form like this

```
<input type="number" name="price" value="<?php echo $editprice;?>" >
```

but this doesn't work for input with type file.
I try it this way

```
<?php
$sqlch15="SELECT image1 FROM pc where id=$idtoe";
$resultch15= mysqli_query($db, $sqlch15);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultch15))
{
  $editimg1 = "<img src='images/"  .$row['image1']."'>";
} 
?>

<input type="file" name="image1" value = "<?php echo $editimg1;?>">
```

but it doesn't work what is my mistake help me.

Comment: It's not a mistake, it's just not allowed by the browser, for security reasons - you can't try to automate the user selecting a specific file, they have to that themselves manually. It's a way of ensuring the user consents to uploading that file. And anyway it makes no sense to specify $editimg1 as the file because that points to a path on the server, not on the user's machine. So even if it was allowed, your idea wouldn't work

Comment: you can't, because of security reasons

Comment: what do you want to fill there, the location on the client computer, the upload location, or the raw picture ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you press that button you upload a picture into the /tmp folder of the server (or another folder designed for that)

You will create a Array variable called $_FILES['image']

```
[_FILES] => Array
    (
        [image1] => Array
            (
                [name] => example.png
                [type] => image/png
                [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpq0JHjV  // that is the upload folder
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 10847
            )
    )
```

So the only thing that would make a little sense is to fill in the name of the file

```
<input type="file" name="image1" value="<?=$_FILES['image']['name'];?>">
```

But as I said it makes no much sense because the info about the path to this file on the client is missing.

Answer (score 1):

The value property contains the complete path of the file.
The value property of the input:file element is read-only, because of security reasons.